# Need to serialize Bitmap in Windows32 mode

Tags: c#, c++

I'm using gdi32 Bitmap...
Need some Win32 solution to serialize gdi32 Bitmap into stream, then pass its buffer to upper level C# code, and to be able to make deserialization...

I know how to do that in MFC, but need Windows 32..

the reason is -

Being not so strong with linking Managed C# code to Unmanaged MFC Dll, I need help and sample of how to bind that kind of link.

Thanks for ya help

Comment: GDI doesn't have any support for this.  You need a library, GDI+ jumps to mind.

Answer (score 1):

By far the simplest way to do this is to pass your `HBITMAP` to the C# code and use [`Image.FromHbitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx).

Comment: David, Image.FromHbitmap will destroy gdi32 format of the Bitmap and build it as gdi+ Bitmap. This is bad for me. I need to keep it in gdi32 Device Independent Bitmap (DIB) to send over network...

Comment: @Kirk When you say you want to deserialize in C#, what do you want to deserialize into?

Comment: 2David: I want to keep it as CDIBFrame object inside C++ and pass just CDIBFrame* outside to c#. >.NET shall not know anything about that lowlevel object, but keep its handle only.
Managing of the object should be passed to unmanaged code only.

Comment: What is CDIBFrame? I don't find that with web search. `CBitmap` has `GetBitmapBits` FWIW.

Comment: Yes, I'm considering to pass out bitmap bits array and BITMAPINFO structure as a reserved way...
I just looking for something where I would say:

Bitmap.Save(stream, Format.PNG), then pass its buffer to c#

I know that would'n be possible with WinAPI, but it is possible inside MFC... that is why the second part of my question is how to work with MFC C++ dll from managed code? Basic principles..
Maybe I need several simple _dllexport functions for C# p/Invoke, and those severals will use MFC Classes? I just no idea of how to use mfc classes in that case.
Can't find any sound example in web.

Comment: Why are you prepared to serialize via PNG, but not via GDI+? That's odd. Now it makes a lot more sense to use PNG over the wire because of the compression. But once again, `Image.FromHbitmap` would be a perfect start to that process.

Comment: :What is CDIBFrame? Sorry, missed ya Q. It's just my own class with all DIB details.
Also, if you lk\ike me to set ya answer accepted, i'll do it anyway.

Comment: @Kirk Well, I'm very happy to have the answer accepted, but I'd only want that if it actually answered your question. I'm not sure that's the case, or is it?!

Comment: >That's odd. Now it makes a lot more sense to use PNG over the wire because of the compression
 I know that, I use double compression. PNG + zLib. PNG is still too much even if the image is black. U'd open MSPaint, then make 1000*1000 bitmap of the black color, then save it as PNG, then save as BMP then compress by 7zip.. the difference about 20 times in size.

Comment: Well, you right about just forget about MFC and such and get buffer and BITMAPINFO structure... then get the same BITMAPINFO in c# with [Serializable] attribute, prepare packet with serialized structure + buffer itself.
That would be easier..

Comment: If you already have the DIB bits then you can just pass them up to C#, compress, onto the wire etc. Is that what your last comment means?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1593/discussion-between-kirk-robb-and-david-heffernan)